# C++ Project not building. No output files are produced

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, build, msbuild, solution

I have a solution with multiple C# projects included, and a single C++ project.

The C++ project is a .NET Framework bootstrapper that should produce a native executable file. I first built the project as a single project solution, however i'm now trying to migrate it into a master solution.

In order to migrate it, I added a new project called Setup to my existing solution called Master. I then added each header, source and resource by adding new files and copy-pasting the content.

I also changed the output directory to `$(Configuration)\` so that it doesn't put the Debug and Release folders in the root folder of the solution.

Now, when I attempt to build the project, it says **Rebuild All Succeeded**, however when i try to debug it i get the following error

**Unable to start the program ~ The system cannot find the file specified**

[Image of error shown when attempting to debug (F5)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dvx5.png)

If i navigate to the output directories, they are empty.

This is my first attempt at a C++ project, have i made a schoolboy error?

Does anyone know how I can get this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. It was indeed a schoolboy error.

I was targeting AnyCPU, whereas i **should have been targeting x86**.

Now that i'm targeting the correct architecture, the project builds as expected.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution here, you could mark it as the answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issues.

Comment: Thanks good advice, it was my intention although there is a time limit before I was allowed to accept my own answer.